# Django unittest assertRedirects explanation of work

Tags: python, django, unit-testing

I need explanation of work assertRedirects function. My view:

```
def login_view(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect('account:profile')
    else:
        form = UserLoginForm(request.POST or None)
        if request.method == 'POST':
            if form.is_valid():
                cd = form.cleaned_data
                user = authenticate(username=cd['username'],
                                    password=cd['password'])
                if user is None:
                    messages.error(request,
                                   'something.')
                else:
                    if user.is_active:
                        login(request, user)
                        next_url = request.POST.get('next',
                                                    reverse('account:profile'))
                        return HttpResponseRedirect(next_url)
                    else:
                        messages.error(request,
                                       'something')
            else:
                messages.error(request, 'something.')

        context = {'form': form,
                   'next': request.GET.get('next')}
        return render(request, 'account/login.html', context)
```

Now I wrote 2 tests.

```
def test_login_view_valid_data_username(self):
    path = reverse('account:login')
    response = self.client.post(path=path,
                                data={'username': 'test123',
                                      'password': 'everything123'})
    # is logged
    self.assertTrue(self.user.is_authenticated)
    # is redirect and good redirected
    self.assertRedirects(response, reverse('account:profile'))
```

My view pass this test. My second test:

```
def test_redirect_url_if_not_login(self):
    path = '{}?next={}'.format(reverse('account:login'),
                               reverse('orders:create'))
    response = self.client.post(path=path,
                                data={'username': 'test123',
                                      'password': 'everything123',
                                      'next': reverse('orders:create')})
    print('RESPONSE CODE', response.status_code)
    print('RESPONSE URL', response.url)
    self.assertRedirects(response, reverse('orders:create'))
```

And here I have problem. I get error:
**AssertionError: 302 != 200 : Couldn't retrieve redirection page '/orders/create/': response code was 302 (expected 200)**
but my response code and response url is correct to reverse path. I'm little bit confusion, because is not the first case like this. Is there any formal explanation of this?

EDIT:

```
@login_required
def create_view(request):
    cart = Cart(request)

    if len(cart) == 0 or not cart:
        return redirect('shop:overview')

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = OrderCreateForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            order = form.save(commit=False)
            order.user = request.user
            order.save()
            for item in cart:
                OrderItem.objects.create(order=order,
                                         product=item['product'],
                                         price=item['price'],
                                         quantity=item['quantity'])
            cart.clear()
            return redirect('orders:payment', id=order.id)
    else:
        data = model_to_dict(request.user.shippingdetails)

        form = OrderCreateForm(data)

    return render(request, 'orders/create.html', {'cart': cart,
                                                  'form': form})
```

Thanks for any answer
Magnus

Comment: Where do you set `self.user`? `self.user.is_authenticated` is testing the user of the test class. That's not the same as testing the user in the test client.

Comment: self. user is defined in setUp function         `self.user = User.objects.create_user(username='test123',
                                             email='testowy@gmail.com',
                                             password='everything123')`. Two tests redirects pages, in one test it work with assertRedirections function, but in second not.  Second test return correct response code - 302, and correct url /orders/create/' but assertRedirects fails.

Comment: Try adding `follow=True` to the `self.client.post(...)`, then print(response.redirect_chain)` to see where you are being redirected to.

Comment: Two tests go to else case, not stop in if condition.

Comment: Look. For first test **RESPONSE CODE 302
RESPONSE URL /account/profile/
<HttpResponseRedirect status_code=302, "text/html; charset=utf-8", url="/account/profile/">**

Comment: For second test **RESPONSE CODE 302
RESPONSE URL /orders/create/
<HttpResponseRedirect status_code=302, "text/html; charset=utf-8", url="/orders/create/">**

Comment: Problem: In first case assertRedirects passed, in second fails.

Comment: Yes, I understand that it fails in the second case. My suggestion above is to figure out why it fails in the second case.

Comment: response.redirect_chain: `<HttpResponseRedirect status_code=302, "text/html; charset=utf-8", url="/account/profile/">
.[('/orders/create/', 302), ('/', 302)]` It's go to '/' because `@login_required
def create_view(request):
    cart = Cart(request)

    if len(cart) == 0 or not cart:
        return redirect('shop:overview')`

Comment: Added full create_view to post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, [`assertRedirects`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.SimpleTestCase.assertRedirects) fetches the target URL and expects a status of 200.

In your case, your view redirects to `/orders/create/` which then redirects to `/`. You can either set `fetch_redirect_response=False` to prevent the test client from fetching `/orders/create/`, or set `target_status_code=302`.